# Is there a way to pass an Angular 2 attribute directive a function

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-directives

In Angular 1, you could pass a function as an argument to an attribute directive using &. I know you can pass a function as input to an element directive (component) in Angular 2 using the

```
<custom-component [callback]="myCallbackFuncton">
..etc
</custom-component>
```

syntax, but is there a way to do this with an attribute directive only? I can only get a string (which does allow me to look the function up off the scope) but would prefer to pass the function in all in one go.
So I would like to be able to write something like this in my template

```
 <form custom-submit="ctrl.register">
 ...etc
 </form>
```

and in the directive js,

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[custom-submit]',
})
@Inject('$element', '$attrs')

export default class CustomSubmit {
    constructor($element, $scope, $attrs) {
        this.$element = $element;

        $element[0].addEventListener('submit', () => {
          // custom validation behaviour
          $attrs.customSubmit();
        });
   }
}
```

Instead of having to write something like

```
 $scope.ctrl[$attrs.customSubmit]()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this:

**@Output is better**

**Use @Output** [Plunk online demo @Output](https://plnkr.co/edit/ADDLvk?p=preview)

**app/custom-submit.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, Output, HostListener, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
  selector: '[custom-submit]'
})
export class CustomSubmit {
  constructor(
    // ...
  ) { }

  @Output('custom-submit') customSubmit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  @HostListener('submit', ['$event'])
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('call this');
    this.customSubmit.emit(e);
  }
}
```

**app/app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <form (custom-submit)="onSubmit($event)">
      <div *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4,5,6]">
        {{item}}
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      <p>Status {{ message }}</p>
    </form>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  message: string = '';

  onSubmit(e) {
    console.log(e);
    this.message = 'submitted';
  }
}
```

**USE @Input** [Plunk online demo @Input()](https://plnkr.co/edit/XDToTs?p=preview)

**app/custom-submit.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[custom-submit]'
})
export class CustomSubmit {
  constructor(
    // ...
  ) { }

  @Input('custom-submit') customSubmit: Fn;

  @HostListener('submit', ['$event'])
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('call this');
    this.customSubmit();
  }
}
```

**app/app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <form [custom-submit]="onSubmit">
      <div *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4,5,6]">
        {{item}}
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      <p>Status {{ message }}</p>
    </form>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  message: string = '';
  constructor() {
    // be careful when pass method to other Component Input
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  onSubmit() {
    console.log('submitted');
    this.message = 'submitted';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I get the same result with that - the input is passed as a string not a reference to the function

Comment: `the input is passed as a string not a reference to the function` i don't think so, just log `console.log(this.customSubmit);` you will get real function, not string

Comment: Nice one thanks very much for the demo - I'm not using typescript and must have translated incorrectly the first time :)

Comment: great news, i'm newbie in Angular/Typescript too.